# Jquery Image slider not looping

Tags: jquery, image, loops, slider, radio-button

I am having a problem with some of my JS. I have an image slider which automatically scrolls through the images, and an image can be selected using radio buttons, but the images will only play through once and then stop.

This JSFiddle works best in chrome - https://jsfiddle.net/jw09363f/

Here is the Jquery -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmp = 0;
    $(document).ready(
        function() { 
            tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
            var tid = setInterval(Backslider, 1000);

        }
    );




    function Backslider() {

        if(tmp != 5) {

        $('input[name=controls]:eq(' + (tmp+1) + ')').attr('checked', 'checked'); 
            tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
        }else{ 
        $('input[name=controls]:eq(' + (tmp-5) + ')').attr('checked', 'checked');
tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
        }}

</script>
```

The idea is that each image is labelled 0 - 5, and when it hits 5, it resets the tmp variable to 0. This however does not happen.

I am new to JS and very new to JQ so please be gentle :)

Many thanks in advance and please let me know if any more details are needed :)

Comment: I can't see the line when you reset the tmp variable.

Comment: To trained eyes that could be part of the problem. I will update the code with what I have just put together. Thanks

Comment: Updated. I was under the impression that the IF statement makes sure that the value of tmp is not 5, and keeps adding 1 onto tmp until it equals 5. At that point it would reset to 0. Hope that makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: Without a functional example I can't help too much. I don't see anything wrong in your code, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out, after many hours and I'm so wound up that it was so simple. I have been using .attr to target attributes but in fact it needs to be .prop to loop the slideshow. The code below also includes a trigger so that if the user clicks on a radio button (one for each image) then the slideshow will stop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmp = 0;
    var autoplay=true;
    $(document).ready(
        function() { 
            tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
            var tid = setInterval(Launcher, 5000);
            $(".clicker").click(function(){
        autoplay=false;
    });
        }

    );
 function Launcher() {

        if(autoplay) {
Backslider();
        }}



    function Backslider() {

        if(tmp != 5) {

        $('input[name=controls]:eq(' + (tmp+1) + ')').prop('checked', 'checked'); 
            tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
        }else{ 
        $('input[name=controls]:eq(' + (0) + ')').prop('checked', 'checked');
tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
        }}

</script>
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell very well from the javascript, how many images are showing at a time? If not all five, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var first = true;
    var tmp = 0;
    $(document).ready(
        function() { 
            tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
            var tid = setInterval(Backslider, 1000);

        }
    );




    function Backslider() {

        if(tmp != 6) {

        $('input[name=controls]:eq(' + (tmp+1)%6 + ')').attr('checked', 'checked'); 
            tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());
        }else{ 
        $('input[name=controls]:eq(' + (tmp-5)%6 + ')').attr('checked', 'checked');
tmp = parseInt($('input[name=controls]:checked').val());

if (!first)
{
    $('input[name="controls"]:first').appendTo($('input[name="controls"]:last'));
}
first = false;
        }}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately still having the same problem :( You're correct, I am only showing one picture at a time. I will quickly do a jsfiddle

Comment: Still no joy I'm afraid :( Thanks for the help though